# Error while converting API data to JSON in FLASK REQUESTS

Tags: json, api, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch data from a API and tried using Json() but brings up this error, couldn't find why,

```
line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
StopIteration: 0 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

My code:

```
re = requests.get("https://public-api.solscan.io/account/tokens?account=yS9M9VJmV5v55VPN1NH8UC2UqXeGpQ2GKXWJ3v6gNDD")
print(re.json())
```

It would be great if someone can help me with this, Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you provided could not raise such error as `StopIteration`. Add your rest code as well.

Comment: Are you getting an okay response with the request (200?)